# Is there a single word for "lack of communication/coordination"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> The accident happened due to a lack of communication (or coordination) between the parties involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Miscommunication** — [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/miscommunication)

> *noun* Failure to communicate ideas or intentions successfully
>
> *"A spokeswomen blamed the confusion on miscommunication between the company and its customers.*"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **disconnect** ([Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/miscommunication))

> A situation in which two or more things are not connected in the way
>   that they should be.

better indicates the missed opportunity to communicate, if that's your intention.

**[Breakdown](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/breakdown)** also sometimes gets used in this sense, though the assumption that it refers to communication (rather than, for instance, their automobile) may be a little more ambiguous in certain situations or audiences.

Answer (score 0):

**Confusion** has a couple definitions along this line: [[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confusion)]

> a situation in which people are uncertain about what to do or are
>   unable to understand something clearly

and

> the feeling that you have when you do not understand what is
>   happening, what is expected, etc.

So it would be: "the accident happened due to confusion between the parties involved."